# Add Text editor to my web application

Tags: asp.net

I need a text editor that I can add as a component to my ASP.net web application, but I need an extra feature in it, it's watermarking. Can you help me?

I mean text watermark like "Confidential" word in the following image.

[image]

Comment: This would be better asked on SO.  But don't re-post it there at this point. If other's agree it will be moved there.

Answer (score 0):

You can take care of the watermarking in CSS.

Here is an example text field:

```
<input type="text" name="yourtextfield" class="one" />
```

Corresponding CSS:

```
.one {
    /* Be sure to set your Width: and Height: parameters */
    background: url(../images/textfield-design/confidential.svg) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px 0 0 5px;
}
```

Basically, any HTML text editing tool can be enhanced in that way.  Using SVG instead of a GIF or JPG allows the watermark to remain clear on those browsers that support it (Firefox, IE 8+, Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) or [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) if you need extra features.